# Appending template.content.cloneNode(true) multiple times not working

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

This does not work:

```js
let template = document.getElementById("template");
const templateContentCloned = template.content.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(templateContentCloned);
document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(templateContentCloned);
document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(templateContentCloned);
```

```html
<template id="template">
  <p>Here is my paragraph.</p>
</template>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

But this does:

```js
let template = document.getElementById("template");
const templateContent = template.content;
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<template id="template">
  <p>Here is my paragraph.</p>
</template>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Why? Why do you have to clone the node every time you want to use the template?

Comment: Because cloneNode **creates** the actual clone, and appenChild **moves** a node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template.content` contains a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) it can only be inserted into DOM once:

> A common use for DocumentFragment is to create one, assemble a DOM subtree within it, then append or insert the fragment into the DOM
> using Node interface methods such as appendChild() or insertBefore().
> **Doing this moves the fragment's nodes into the DOM, leaving behind an
> empty DocumentFragment**

So after it was inserted into `div1` variable `templateContentCloned` become an empty `documentFragment` hens nothing inserted into `div2` and `div3`

Comment: But a quick inspection shows that the `p` does not move through `div1` to `div2` to `div3` but rather gets stuck on `div1`, which is not what you wrote. Can you explain this?

Comment: Oh, you are correct, I didn't actually test it. I've update the answer